# Is there a Firefox toolbar extension to enclose selected text with html tags?

Tags: firefox, html, firefox-extensions, markup

While writing on StackOverflow and other community web resources I very frequently have to enclose pieces of text in  "blockquote", "em", "pre+code", "a" etc tags, and enter them (even both - opening and closing) manually all the time.

Isn't there a Firefox extension to facilitate this? So that I could just select a piece of text, press a button, and it will be enclosed in a tag I want?

Answer (score 1):

And here it is, nicely served up, and ready for you to use:
[Markitup Script](https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/69807)

Read it up about how to use (click on 'Toggle markItUp' button!!) [here](http://scratch99.com/web-development/greasemonkey/scripts/markitup-for-greasemonkey/)

And lets not forget [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) itself.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have a look at [Colt](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1812/).